# Facebook API não abre no phonegap app mobile

Tags: apache-cordova, api

Bom, utilizi o plugin do phonegap facebbok, ele funciona normalmente no browser, mas no aplicativo não gera nenhum resultado.

Eu chamo no app desta maneira:

```
$scope.sharethisfuckingshit = function(){            
        console.log('aqui');
        facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog( 
        {
            method: "feed",
            picture:'https://www.google.co.jp/logos/doodles/2014/doodle-4-google-2014-japan-winner-5109465267306496.2-hp.png',
            name:'Test Post',
            message:'First photo post',    
            caption: 'Testing using phonegap plugin',
            description: 'Posting photo using phonegap facebook plugin'
        }, 
        function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
        function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
      }
```

Essa é minha library:

```
/* global cordova */
if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {   
cordova.define("com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect.FacebookConnectPlugin", function(require, exports, module) {        

    "use strict";

    /*
    * @author Ally Ogilvie
    * @copyright Wizcorp Inc. [ Incorporated Wizards ] 2014
    * @file - facebookConnectPlugin.js
    * @about - JavaScript interface for PhoneGap bridge to Facebook Connect SDK
    *
    *
    */

    var exec = require("cordova/exec");

    var facebookConnectPlugin = {

        getLoginStatus: function (s, f) {
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "getLoginStatus", []);
        },

        showDialog: function (options, s, f) {
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "showDialog", [options]);
        },

        login: function (permissions, s, f) {
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "login", permissions);
        },

        logEvent: function(name, params, valueToSum, s, f) {
            // Prevent NSNulls getting into iOS, messes up our [command.argument count]
            if (!params && !valueToSum) {
                exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "logEvent", [name]);
            } else if (params && !valueToSum) {
                exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "logEvent", [name, params]);
            } else if (params && valueToSum) {
                exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "logEvent", [name, params, valueToSum]);
            } else {
                f("Invalid arguments");
            }
        },

        logPurchase: function(value, currency, s, f) {
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "logPurchase", [value, currency]);
        },

        getAccessToken: function(s, f) {
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "getAccessToken", []);
        },

        logout: function (s, f) {
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "logout", []);
        },

        api: function (graphPath, permissions, s, f) {
            if (!permissions) { permissions = []; }
            exec(s, f, "FacebookConnectPlugin", "graphApi", [graphPath, permissions]);
        }
    };


    module.exports = facebookConnectPlugin;
});
  }
    else { window.facebookConnectPlugin = window.facebookConnectPlugin || {

    getLoginStatus: function (s, f) {
        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                s(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },

    showDialog: function (options, s, f) {

        if (!options.name) {
            options.name = "";
        }
        if (!options.message) {
            options.message = "";
        }
        if (!options.caption) {
            options.caption = "";
        }
        if (!options.description) {
            options.description = "";
        }
        if (!options.href) {
            options.href = "";
        }
        if (!options.picture) {
            options.picture = "";
        }

        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.ui(options,
            function (response) {
                if (response && (response.request || !response.error_code)) {
                    s(response);
                } else {
                    f(response);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },
    // Attach this to a UI element, this requires user interaction.
    login: function (permissions, s, f) {
        // JS SDK takes an object here but the native SDKs use array.
        var permissionObj = {};
        if (permissions && permissions.length > 0) {
            permissionObj.scope = permissions.toString();
        }

        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                s(response);
            } else {
                f(response.status);
            }
        }, permissionObj);
    },

    getAccessToken: function (s, f) {
        var response = FB.getAccessToken();
        if (!response) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error("NO_TOKEN");
            } else {
                f("NO_TOKEN");
            }
        } else {
            s(response);
        }
    },

    logEvent: function (eventName, params, valueToSum, s, f) {
        // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
        s();
    },

    logPurchase: function (value, currency, s, f) {
        // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
        s();
    },

    logout: function (s, f) {
        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.logout( function (response) {
                s(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },

    api: function (graphPath, permissions, s, f) {
        // JS API does not take additional permissions

        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.api(graphPath, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    f(response);
                } else {
                    s(response);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },

    // Browser wrapper API ONLY
    browserInit: function (appId, version) {
        if (!version) {
            version = "v2.3";
        }
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
            FB.init({ 
                appId : appId,     
                xfbml : true,
                status: true,
                version: version
            }); 
        }; 
        alert('aqui');
    }
};

// Bake in the JS SDK
(function () {
    // Retrieve the root element to append the script tags to
    var root = document.getElementById('fb-root') || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    if (!window.FB) {
        console.log("launching FB SDK");
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        e.onload = e.onreadystatechange = e.onerror = loadLocalSDK;

        root.appendChild(e);
    }

    /**
     * If something happens when loading the the remote script, then check if
     * window.FB exists, if not, load the local script.
     */
    function loadLocalSDK() {
        if (!window.FB) {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.async = true;
            e.src = 'phonegap/plugin/facebookConnectPlugin/fbsdk.js';

            root.appendChild(e);

            console.log("Attempt local load: ", e);
        }
    }
}());
```

}

Comment: Por que você não usa o plugin para conectar com o facebook app nativo? Se o usuário não tiver o app, abre no browser normalmente

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Estou utilizando esse mesmo plugin, só que tive que modificar algumas coisas pra poder rodar, a questão é que não abre nada no app.